# java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable.Theme_windowNoTitle

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I had created a sample demo app which was working earlier in **Eclipse**, but after updating **Android sdk** build tools to latest version (r22.1) , i am facing these issue:

> java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:
>   android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable.Theme_windowNoTitle

Here is **logcat stacktrace**:

```
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966): Process: com.amrit.demoapp, PID: 19966
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$styleable.Theme_windowNoTitle
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:127)
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.onCreate(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:146)
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966):    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onCreate(AppCompatActivity.java:59)
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966):    at com.amrit.demoapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:60)
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5451)
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1093)
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2295)
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2389)
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:169)
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1277)
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5479)
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
05-07 11:45:28.580: E/AndroidRuntime(19966):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

<style name="AppBaseTheme"  parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">     

</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">

</style>
```

I have tried changing Theme parent to "`Base.Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`" & also tried adding

```
<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item> 
<item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
```

inside `AppBaseTheme`, but nothing worked.

Do anyone knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: did you try cleaning and re-building project?

Comment: Yes, I've tried that also but it didn't work

Comment: Try removing library, then import it again, copy files from **lib** folder in *appcompat-v7* and paste them in your project's **lib** folder

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion finally after re-import it worked

Comment: Glad that I helped you out :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Removing** support library appcompat_v7 from my workspace & **re-importing** it from sdk location

> (\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat)

solved this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If this is simply Rendering issue ,

You have to do two things:

1. be sure to have imported right appcompat-v7 library in your project 
   structure -> dependencies
2. change the theme in the preview window to not an AppCompat theme. Try    with Holo.light or Holo.dark for example.

Answer (score 1):

you project -> properties -> Java Build Path -> Order and export -> Select All.
hope it works to you!

Answer (score 0):

It worked !!

Removing support library appcompat_v7 from my workspace & re-importing it from sdk location

```
(\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20140702\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat)
```

Comment: Yes I know, but instead of commenting why you are posting same answer again?

Comment: @Amrit, Actually wasn't able to comment because of not enough rank/ points on stackoverflow. So just wanted to mention that this trick resolved the problem